# Upgrade from SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server

Can I develop the system using SQL Server Express and then switch to a SQL Server (with the same scheme) using the same code (except connection obviously) when I deploy?

Assume that I only use features available in both versions.

Comment: So... you are only using features common to both variants of the SQL Server version you are using and you are seriously asking if you can use the same schema and code.

Comment: Course you can. Mind that ume can and will make an ass of you....

Comment: Yes, of course. SQL Server Express is just a specific *edition* of SQL Server - it's the **FULL** SQL Server at its core, the `.mdf` files are 100% identical.

Comment: Yes - http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=67639

Comment: i know i can use the same schema and SQL code. i'm asking if my c# code will change. like do i use different SQLConnection classes?

Comment: Nothing need to be changed but only connection string

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can, that's what am I doing now

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Just be careful when you do the move to make sure that your SQL Express instance is at the same service pack level (or lower) than your new SQL Standard/Developer/Enterprise edition, because if it's not, your databases won't attach... People can sometimes get confused about that when they make the switch.